# After using imwrite function to save image, some of images cannot open

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

the code is shown below:

```
    minv = np.min(saliency_map)
    maxv = np.max(saliency_map)
    cscale = 255/(maxv-minv)
    shift = -1*(minv)
    dst = np.zeros(imgsize[1]*imgsize[0], dtype='uint8')
    dst = cv2.convertScaleAbs(saliency_map,dst,cscale,shift/255.0)
    cv2.imwrite(filename, dst)
```

Saliency_map is a matrix which contains float32 value, so I use convertScaleAbs function to convert the matrix to image. But some images cannot open.
Someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the line where you instantiate dst using np.zeros will not yield the desired result as the shape you have passed is just a single number, not `(imgsize[1],imgsize[0])`
In fact, it is not required at all (directly writing `dst = cv2.convertScaleAbs()` will work)

As for a solution, you can generate the `uint8` matrix with one line too. Try this:

`minv = np.min(saliency_map)
maxv = np.max(saliency_map)
u_img = np.array( (saliency_map-minv)/(maxv-minv)*255, dtype=np.uint8 )
cv2.imwrite('test.png', u_img)`

Comment: Thanks. I fix it using your method.